# Html Agility Pack: Get an HTML document from an Internet resource and saves it to the specified file

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to get the html page from this link and store the content into a specific file in C# using the HAP Class library. I amusing the Get method of the HtmlWeb class. It compiles and runs perfectly fine but the "file.txt" is never created. Here is the class and its client.Can anyone help please:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace WebCrawler
{
    class Crawler
    {
        public Crawler() { }

        public Crawler(string Url)
        {
            this.Url = Url;
            HtmlWeb page = new HtmlWeb();
            Console.WriteLine(Url);
            HtmlDocument doc = page.Load(Url);
            page.Get(Url, "file.txt");
        }

        public string Url
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace WebCrawler
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Crawler crawler = new Crawler("https://code.google.com/p/abot/");
        }
    }
}


    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace WebCrawler
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Crawler crawler = new Crawler("https://code.google.com/p/abot/");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call Save method for object of HtmlDocument type. Here's example of loading index page of Google website and saving it to out.html file.

```
const string url = "http://google.com";

HtmlWeb page = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument document = page.Load(url);
page.Get(url, "/");
document.Save("out.html");
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do something like this

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"c:\file.txt", doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml);
```